# Hive job on Tez execution engine fails on memory allocation

Tags: memory, parquet, apache-tez

org.apache.parquet.hadoop.MemoryManager$1: New Memory allocation 1046531 bytes is smaller than the minimum allocation size of 1048576 bytes.

Comment: Versions are not specified in description, but i remember that there was a memory leak issue on parquet https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-783 due to not closed FSDataInputStream. Due to the issue, tez jobs are killed by node manager. Effect version is 1.9.0 and fix version is 1.10.0. This might be the reason.